# WPF How to put button into row which is inside column

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

How can I put button into row which is inside column?

```
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50" MinHeight="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

Grid.Row="2" is out of index. Grid.Colum="1" puts the button into correct column. What might be the correct way to use those rows?

Comment: Your question itself is not well phrased. What you want is to insert a button into a Grid inside of another Grid.

Comment: And this is one of the _most_ basics things you learn in WPF, so I suggest you read up on the basics. [This](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/) might be a good start and there's tons of other resources on the Internet.

Comment: You can use `<Grid ShowGridLines="True">` to see how your Grid element looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial row index guess was correct.  You just need to put your button in the proper place in your XAML.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300" Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50" MinHeight="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="2"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```